# Unable to create new Azure SQL VM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

Deployment template validation failed:

```
 The template resource 'xxx/SqlIaasExtension' at line '1' and column '5024' is not valid:
 The resource identificator 'xxx/ManagedIdentityExtensionForWindows' is malformed. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.
```

Anyone else have experience with this while using the new VM wizard?  I attempted to create the VM with SQL Server 2014 under Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Can you post the ARM template files that you are use for this deployment? That would be useful for folks here to see what the potential problems are. In general, posting just an error message will not be sufficient.

Comment: I didn't use any template files; I used the portal wizard to do it

Comment: Hi @MikeH . How did you create this VM? Did you create this with the  SQL Server 2014 SP2 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012R2 image from marketplace?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT I am experiencing the same error when trying to create a "Free License: SQL Server 2016 SP1 Developer on Windows Server 2016" VM via the Azure portal. The only difference is that it's line 1 and column 5158. The error is not displayed if No is selected for Managed service identity on the Settings blade.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT still haven't managed to create the VM; I attempted to use both Standard and Enterprise versions (Server 2016) on (now) various VM sku's.  Most recently was E2v3 and D2v3.

Comment: Let me do a deep test and keep you updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **No** under **Managed service identity** on the **Settings** blade to resolve the error.

This is still a problem if you require the Managed service identity feature, but you can at least create the VM by selecting No.

[image]

Comment: Does this mean I'll be limited to SQL auth to access to the SQL instance?

Comment: I gave it a try and it does work.  While this is technically an answer, I have a ticket with Azure support so they know of this problem.